# How to minify inline css using twig in drupal 8?

Tags: twig, drupal-8, theming

Inside my html.html.twig template I've added a stylesheet inside the style elements using this;

```
{% include directory ~ '/css/base/style.css' %}
```

Is there a way that I can strip it for all whitespaces? Can I apply the CssOptimizer class to it in any way?

Answer (score 0):

You could try to use the [spaceless Tag](http://twig.sensiolabs.org/doc/tags/spaceless.html)

```
{% spaceless %}
{% include directory ~ '/css/base/style.css' %}
{% endspaceless %}
```

Comment: Thanks, but it doesnt help, as it is written in the documentation

Comment: Pushed button to early. It is written: "remove whitespace between HTML tags". CSS != HTML tags

Comment: Is there a way to simply include the .min version of your styles?
For my AMP pages for example we run css-nano via grunt before inlining the styles.